# Integration of Annotatorjs lib with Angular 4 (ionic application)

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, annotatorjs

I'm trying to use the Annotatorjs library http://annotatorjs.org version 1.2.0 or 2.x.x in my Ionic 3 app (using Angular4).

I tried the 1.2.7 version (latest 1.2.x) :

```
let el =  this.el.nativeElement;
el.annototar()
```

But I get this error : *TypeError: aa.annotator is not a function TypeError: aa.annotator is not a function*

I also tried with the v2 : 
    var app = new annotator.App();

```
let el =  this.el.nativeElement;
app.include(annotator.ui.main, {
  element: el
});
app.start();
```

I do not have any errors here but nothing happens (none annotations actions are displayed when I try to select some text in the element div)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If someone has the same problem just use the *new version* https://hypothes.is !